# Insert csv file to mysql table OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied error

Tags: python

I am trying to insert csv file to mysql table using sub process.call from other script  but receiving this error.I don't know  where  am i  going wrong I checked my file and everything looks fine.

```
 def ringoCallback3(filename):
            #Run the RINGO  insert script
            tmp = filename.split('/')
            just_filename = tmp[-1]
            new_filename = "/home/toor/doneringofiles/%s" % just_filename
            retval = subprocess.call(["/usr/local/bin/ringo.py",filename])
            os.rename(filename, new_filename)
            return retval
    dirlist = [ ['/home/toor/ringolist',ringoCallback3]]

    while (True):
        # Go through each of the directories
        for mylist in dirlist:
            check_dir = mylist[0]
            callback = mylist[1]

            # get the list of files in the directory
            filelist = os.listdir(check_dir)
            for this_file in filelist:
                if ((this_file == ".") or (this_file == "..") or (this_file == "doneringofiles")):
                    print "Skipping self and parent"
                    continue

                full_filename = "%s/%s" % (check_dir, this_file)

                # Get the modification time of the file
                first_stat = os.stat(full_filename)[8]

                # Sleep for 1 second
                time.sleep(1)

                # Get the modification time again
                second_stat = os.stat(full_filename)[8]

                # If the modication time has not changed, then the file is stable
                # and can be sent to the callback
                if (first_stat == second_stat):
                    callback(full_filename)

        # Now sleep for 30 seconds before doing the whole lot again
        time.sleep(30)
```

When I run this code : I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./dirmon.py", line 80, in <module>
        callback(full_filename)
      File "./dirmon.py", line 44, in ringoCallback3
        retval = subprocess.call(["/usr/local/bin/ringo.py",filename])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
        return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: ?? Where is your username and password for it?

Comment: Its called from other script  ringo.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This caused because `/usr/local/bin/ringo.py` is not executable by the user that your script is running as.

You can check this, by trying to run the script from a shell (as the same user that your script runs as):

```
$ /usr/local/bin/ringo.py
```

You either need to make it executable with the `chmod` command, or call the subprocess like this:

```
subprocess.call(["python", "/usr/local/bin/ringo.py",filename])
```